# Text data using logistic regression

Tags: python, nlp, logistic-regression

I am working on a pre-processing phase with this data:

```
Name   Nickname   Age    Country    Reg_Date     Text 
Matt   LeBron    63     Canada     24-12-2008   I'm in a happy mood today. I go to beach
Chris  Severine  54     U.S.       15-07-2009   I stand in solidarity with #ows
Lucas  Daly      47     Ireland    01-05-2020   Trump is working for next politician...
Clash  Lynch     24     U.S.       13-11-2008   What a wonderful day!
...
```

I need is to use Bag of Words or another feature representation before splitting my dataset into training and test set and use it for a logistic regression.

Currently I tried to get other information from the original dataset above (number of characters in a tweet; use of punctuations, and so on):

```
Name   Nickname   Age    Country    Reg_Date     Text 
Matt   LeBron    63     Canada     24-12-2008   I'm in a happy mood today. I go to beach
Chris  Severine  54     U.S.       15-07-2009   I stand in solidarity with #ows
Lucas  Daly      47     Ireland    01-05-2020   Trump is working with Putin... 
Clash  Lynch     24     U.S.       13-11-2008   What a wonderful day!
...
Lulu   Lulu22    18     Poland     02-09-2019   I hate Maths!!!! >(


Punctuation   Positive Words     Negative Words
[.]          [happy]              []
[#]          [solidarity]         []
[...]        []                   []
[!]          [wonderful]          []
[>,(]        []                   [hate]
```

Now, I would really like to understand how I can transform punctuation information, positive words, negative words, text in a way that can be 'readable' for a model (for example in a logistic regression model).

I would appreciate if you could give me some useful tips or provide an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [One hot encoding](https://machinelearningmastery.com/why-one-hot-encode-data-in-machine-learning/)
Or [word embedding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_embedding)

For more information about nlp in general you can read the notes from [Stanford's cs224N course](https://web.stanford.edu/class/archive/cs/cs224n/cs224n.1194/). More specifically [this](https://web.stanford.edu/class/archive/cs/cs224n/cs224n.1194/readings/cs224n-2019-notes01-wordvecs1.pdf)

Comment: Hi @YukiShriorii, thank you for your answer and the recommendation. I have started to read the Stanford document. Having a dataset with a mix with text data and numerical data, how can I use one hot encoding or word embedding to treat all the text data as numerical variables?For example, I have the column Text, Punctuation and Positive/negative words. In my classifier, they should be also considered as I could find a good predictor the number of positive words or just the use of <3 in a text to see that the polarity (or alternatively the sentiment) can be positive.

Comment: What are you trying to predict ?

Comment: I would like to predict the sentiment of a text but using a classifier (e.g. logistic regression or svm). I feel I am missing something in the understanding of steps. I also determined the word frequency of one-grams, bi-grams and 3-grams... but I have not understood how to use this information in a classifier

Comment: You can check [this](https://machinelearningmastery.com/deep-learning-bag-of-words-model-sentiment-analysis/)

Comment: For example your data consists of [ "i hate sand," "i love you" ] -> total of 5 different words (i, hate, love, sand, you) -> apply one hot -> [ (1, 1, 0, 1, 0), (1, 0, 1, 0, 1)] ->input into the model and it should learn that data with the word hate or love belong to neg/positive label respectively

Comment: Thanks Yuki. In this document it seems clear that I need to encode the training data, tokenizer.texts_to_matrix(df, mode='freq'). But what would happen to columns that are not text (age, for example)? Should I use tokeniser for each text column?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220151/discussion-between-yukishioriii-and-val).